# Get content between parentheses on two lines

Tags: ruby, regex

Is it possible to get the content between parentheses while the brackets are on two lines?
Something like:

```
aaaa = ("bbb",

   "ccc")
```

and output:

```
"bbb","ccc"
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Will you only have one set of parentheses in the string or can there be multiple assignments and multiple sets of parentheses? Will there be embedded parentheses? That makes a big difference in possible answers.

Comment: only one set of parentheses in the string

Comment: You could accept an answer if one of the answers answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a multi-line regex. It works like a normal regex but with the `/m` flag newlines will be matched by `.`.

```
string = %Q'aaaa = ("bbb",\n\n"ccc")'

string =~ /\((.*)\)/m

puts $1.gsub(/\s/,'') # prints "bbb","ccc"
```

I'm using `gsub` here to strip out whitespace but that's optional.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = 'aaaa = ("bbb",

   "ccc")'

results = []

str.scan(/" .* "/x) do |quoted_str|
  results << quoted_str
end


puts results.join(',')

--output:--
"bbb","ccc"
```